# A little help with $ x_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[ k \alpha \right] $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So I have this little problem I want to solve that says the following:

For every number $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} $, analyze the following sequence
$$ \{ x_n \} = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[ k \alpha \right] ,$$ where $ \left[ x \right] $ is the floor function. Calculate for which values of $ \alpha $ does $ x_n $ converges, or if it diverges. If it converges, calculate the limit of the sequence.

My first thought was to prove that this sequence converges, or diverges, for every possible value of $ \alpha $, that is, when $ \alpha \in \mathbb{Z} ,$ $ \alpha \in \mathbb{Q} ,$ and when $ \alpha \in \mathbb{I} ,$ in other words, $ \alpha $ is irrational.

So when $ \alpha \in \mathbb{Z} $ I got the following:
If $ \alpha \in \mathbb{Z} $ then $ \left[ \alpha \right] = \alpha ,$ therefore
$$ \{ x_n \} = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \alpha = \frac{\alpha}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} k = \frac{\alpha}{n^2} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{\alpha (n+1)}{2n} ,$$
thus, $ \{ x_n \} $ converges to $$ \{ x_n \} = \frac{\alpha (n+1)}{2n} ;$$
since it converges, then we can calculate the limit as follows
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \{ x_n \} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\alpha (n+1)}{2n} = \frac{\alpha}{2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n} = \frac{\alpha}{2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 + \frac{1}{n}}{1} = \frac{\alpha}{2} \left[ \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \right] = \frac{\alpha}{2} .$$

So, first of all, is this proof correct? If so, how can I proceed to prove the sequence when $ \alpha \in \mathbb{Q} $ or when it's irrational? Should I prove the floor function for rational and irrational numbers and then apply this to the sequence?

Comment: you mean $x_n = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \ldots $ ?? and write $\lfloor x \rfloor = x  - \{x\} =  x - 1/2 - (\{x\}-1/2)$ with $\{x\} \in [0,1[$ this time the fractional part, $1$-periodic, and with $\{x\}-1/2$ being odd and  zero mean..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow what you want to say. You are telling me to use the properties of the floor function in order to split what is inside of the sum?

Comment: yes : $x_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \alpha k \rfloor =\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha k -\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \{\alpha k\} = \ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$ we have $\lfloor k \alpha\rfloor \leqslant k \alpha < \lfloor k \alpha \rfloor +1 \implies   k\alpha -1 < \lfloor k \alpha \rfloor \leqslant k \alpha.$

Hence,

$$\alpha\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2} - \frac{n}{n^2} =\frac{ 1}{n^2}\sum_{k = 1}^n (\alpha k - 1) < \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k = 1}^n \lfloor k \alpha \rfloor \leqslant \frac{ 1}{n^2}\sum_{k = 1}^n \alpha k = \alpha\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}.$$

Apply the squeeze theorem to evaluate the limit.  The cases where $\alpha \leqslant 0 $ is similar